# Simple PHP error MVC structure

Tags: php, model-view-controller

For a school assignment be have to make a website with a piece of back-end in it. We learned the MVC structure for a clean and logic overview of our folders/classes in php. however, when I try to get 1 item from my database, my browser gives the error 'undefined variable'. After 1,5 days of failed attempts I decided to give it a shot on stackoverflow.
I'm willing to screenshare if someone could help me. explaining my code in here would not make my problem clear i'm affraid :/

Thx in advance,

Bernd

Comment: Please give us more information.

Comment: Please the code for page that is throwing the error; or see this thread on that error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12778634#12778634

Comment: Have found my error after hours en hours of retyping code/searching my fault. The problem was that I used a function filter in my Controller.php but I had also a filter function in my self written controller. result -> he was confused so he decided to not work at all.. Thanks for the responses though.